# Get facebook user id

Tags: facebook, tabs

I have searched the web high and low and can´t figure out the problem I´m facing.  I have a page tab application on Facebook, the user likes the page to start and then he can answer some questions, I can get the facebook connect to function but I can not get the user id and save it to the database.

I have this in my index page

```
<? include('db.php'); 
include_once("config.php");

// Finnur út hvaða spurninga sett á að nota
$sp_set = 1;

require_once 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';
// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook( array('appId' => '289393321124676',
'secret' => 'd47b7871e0a7fb475db6e2a643f675ed', 'cookie' => true, ));
$signed_request = $facebook -> getSignedRequest();
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
$user = $facebook->getUser();

//If the page is liked then display full app.

?>
```

And the user id is always null, when the user submits the questions everything is saved to the database but user is 0.

Please help

Comment: What is in `$signed_request`?

Comment: I thought that would allow me to get some more info about the user...

Comment: I also need that to know if the user has liked the page before he can start answering the questions...

Comment: Do `print_r($signed_request);` and paste the result on here.

Answer (score 0):

> $user = $facebook->getUser();

This will *not* get you any user id, unless the user has connected to your app first.

So you have to implement either the client-side or the server-side Auth flow in your app. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pagetab/

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
<?php

    $secret   = '********************************'; // App Secret 
    $app_id   = '***************';                  // App ID
    $page_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/*******'; // FB fan page URL, where the application tab is installed

    require 'src/facebook.php';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => $app_id,
        'secret' => $secret,
    ));

    // Get User ID
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($user) {
        try {
            // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            $user = null;
        }
    }

    // Login url will be needed depending on current user state.
    if (!$user) {
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri' => $page_url.'?sk=app_'.$app_id));
    }

    $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body><pre>

<?php 

    if (!$user): // isn't authorized
        echo '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'" target="_top">Authorize app</a>';
    else:
        if ($signed_request['page']['liked']): // likes
            echo 'The page is liked by user with id '.$signed_request['user_id'];
        else:
            echo 'The page is <strong>NOT</strong> liked by user with id '.$signed_request['user_id'];
        endif;
    endif;


?>
    </pre></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. I ended up using the FB JS-SDK to invoke the oAuth dialog to allow the user to connect to my app and grant me permissions. At that point you can access their user id and whatever other info they're granted you permission for.

Add the following code to your `window.fbAsyncInit` call:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
 if (response.authResponse) {
  console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
  FB.api('/me', function(response) {
   console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
  });
 } else {
  console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
 }
});
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/